# Emoji flags only work on versions higher than 5.1 android

Tags: java, android, mobile, unicode, unicode-string

The following unicode displays the Canadian flag:

```
"\uD83C\uDDE8\uD83C\uDDE6"
```

This works fine on 8.0 version, but when I switch to 5.1 (Lolipop) in the emulator, I get the country code instead (C A). Is there anyway to display the flag? Or are emojis not supported in Lolipop?

Comment: Facing the same problem. Any Update?